# Alternative to blow hot and cold

Tags: idioms

Is there any alternative to **blow hot and cold** , in a more sarcastic way, in the context of this sentence.

> He has been inconsistence in his view, **blowing hot and cold** and hence appears unconvincing

Comment: That should be 'inconsistent', not 'inconsistence'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found from the Internet:

Synonyms for blow hot and cold

> be on the fence.
> change one's mind.
> chop and change.
> flip-flop.
> fluctuate.
> vacillate.
> will and will not.
> wobble about.